# How to call getWindow() using a method from a listener

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, listener, window-managers

I'm using getwindow to set a lot of stuff at the beginning of bunch of my activities within my onCreate.  I would like to replace this with a method like the following:

```
    public static void initializeScreen (Activity This){
    This.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    if (global.notBarOnOff == true) {
        This.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        This.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);}
    //Keeps Screen on
    This.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    // Controls Screen Brightness
    Settings.System.putInt(This.getContentResolver(), SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams settings = This.getWindow().getAttributes();
    settings.screenBrightness = (float) 0.10;   
    This.getWindow().setAttributes(settings);
}
```

Now I think this will work just fine by calling SCREEN_Controller.initializeScreen(this)

Later I let the user change the brightness by pressing a button.

```
bLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            settings.screenBrightness = (float) 1;
            getWindow().setAttributes(settings);
```

I know to use my initializeScreen I would have to add the following to my listener

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams settings = This.getWindow().getAttributes();
```

So I would like to replace that with a method as well from my SCREEN_Controller class.  The problem is I can't use the (Activity This) that I use previously because it wouldn't let me call the Activity in the setOnClickListener with using new.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the activity `this` in the internal class like this ( `:-)` ):

```
YourClassName.this
```

Two more notes:

- In Java, there's `this` (all lower case), not `This`.
- Instead of writing `this.getWindow().getAttributes();`, you could just write `getWindow().getAttributes();`. As a general rule, if there was no declaration of a variable with the same name in a lower scope, then you can refer to the variable without `this`.

Short example:

```
public class DontMissTwice extends Activity {

    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shaving);
        TextView knife = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.knife);
        knife.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View.OnClickListener thisListener = this; // refers to View.OnClickListener's object
                DontMissTwice thisDontMissTwice = DontMissTwice.this // refers to DontMissTwice's object
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: YourClassName.this worked well.  I was using This in my method as a reminder to use "this" when I called it.  I'm not sure if it was totally clear that I put a method up top not what I have in my activity.  Thanks for your help!